# How to make a two level navigation menu in Bootstrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I need a nav-bar that has two tiers. So Level one might have three entries "Dogs" "Cats" "Birds". Selected "Dogs" would show the 2nd tier menu which might have "Collie" "Terrier" "Yorkie" and so on.

I can't get this to work nor can I find an example on the web. I am not wedded to nav-bars, anything that works would be great.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Responsive Navbar</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
</head> 

<body>


 <div class="container"> 
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
 <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page1">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></li> 
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page1">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </nav>
      <div id="page1" class="page-header">
        <h1>Page 1 Nav</h1>
      </div>  
</div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: here is a working demo.
 http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOEByo?editors=1100

Comment: That works for a drop down, but I was wanting something where the 2nd menu stays where it is when the corresponding top tab is clicked.

Comment: you want 2nd menu to come up when any item in 1st menu is clicked ?

Comment: Yes exactly. That is exactly what I want.